Failed to build docker NVidia ODTK container
I am trying to do a training with NVidia ODTK by following the tutorial from here.
But I received an error message, when I run the following command:
docker build -t odtk:latest retinanet-examples/
This is the error message:
    22.18 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement apex (unavailable) (from odtk) (from versions: 0.9.8dev.linux-i686, 0.9.8.dev0, 0.9.8a0.dev0, 0.9.9.dev0, 0.9.10.dev0)
    22.18 ERROR: No matching distribution found for apex (unavailable)

Is the same issue described here on NVidia forum, but no solution offered.
I am using:

Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Docker version 26.1.0, build 9714adc
CUDA Version: 12.4
tensorrt 10.0.1.6-1+cuda12.4

Update
I think I found the issue regarding the apex framework. If you look inside the Dockerfile from the apex repo, which is cloned to disk while building the docker image, you may notice that the base image is nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:19.07-py3. But under retinanet-examples folder there are 2 other docker files:

Dockerfile - with base image nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:21.09-py3
Dockerfile.deepstream - with base image nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:20.03-py3

I updated the last 2 docker files from above to start from the same image version as apex. As a result, the building process passed over building the apex framework.
I needed to do a new change in file csrc\extensions.cpp by replacing at line 175 buffers.push_back(buffer.data_ptr<float>()); with buffers.push_back(buffer.data_ptr());.
When compiling again I received lots of compiling errors. Bellow I listed first of them (there are many more).
36.12     csrc/plugins/DecodePlugin.h:40:49: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
36.12      class DecodePlugin : public IPluginV2DynamicExt {
36.12                                                      ^
36.12     csrc/plugins/DecodePlugin.h:117:3: error: ‘DimsExprs’ does not name a type
36.12        DimsExprs getOutputDimensions(int outputIndex, const DimsExprs *inputs,
36.12        ^~~~~~~~~
36.12     csrc/plugins/DecodePlugin.h:128:49: error: ‘PluginTensorDesc’ does not name a type
36.12        bool supportsFormatCombination(int pos, const PluginTensorDesc *inOut,
36.12                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
36.12     csrc/plugins/DecodePlugin.h:141:33: error: ‘PluginTensorDesc’ does not name a type
36.12        size_t getWorkspaceSize(const PluginTensorDesc *inputs,
36.12                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
36.12     csrc/plugins/DecodePlugin.h:142:25: error: ‘PluginTensorDesc’ does not name a type
36.12          int nbInputs, const PluginTensorDesc *outputs, int nbOutputs) const noexcept override
36.12                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
36.12     csrc/plugins/DecodePlugin.h:152:21: error: ‘PluginTensorDesc’ does not name a type
36.12        int enqueue(const PluginTensorDesc *inputDesc,
36.12                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
36.12     csrc/plugins/DecodePlugin.h:153:11: error: ‘PluginTensorDesc’ does not name a type
36.12          const PluginTensorDesc *outputDesc, const void *const *inputs,
36.12                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                       
...

It seems that the compiler doesn't recognize the types from TensorRT.
I have TensorRT properly installed on my linux machine and all its include files are at /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu path.
I also modify LD_LIBRARY_PATH before running the docker command as:
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

How can I solve these last errors?
